# How to display an audio file from backend in HTML and React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, frontend

I have a program where backend sends an audio file to React frontend. But it is not getting displayed as expected.

Here is the code in frontend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2jXm.png)

And here is the response. The audio file is in **res.data**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjW1x.png)

After doing a little research, I am displaying audio file as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGy1N.png)

But it shows empty audio player.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeBAw.png)

What am I doing wrong here, as I am getting audio file when I test it in Postman

Comment: The src attribute of the `HTMLAudioElement` is expecting a URL. I would convert the data to a `Blob` and use `URL.createObjectURL()` to get a src-URL for the element.

Comment: Please post your code as code, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @Seabyte i have tried it, not sure if doing it exactly right.  const audioArray = new Uint8Array(res.data);
          const blob = new Blob([audioArray], { type: 'audio/mp3' });
          setAudio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

Comment: @Seabyte and also this way const blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'audio/mp3' });
          setAudio(URL.createObjectURL(blob)).   Got both from chat.openai

Comment: @MuhammadTalha Have you tried setting the `responseType` property in `axios.post` to `"blob"` and skipping the conversion stuff? I think the default response type might be JSON...